# stored procedure to support unicode characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, unicode

i have this stored procedure

```
ALTER PROC [Resource_Control].[sp_LocationsInsert] 
@name nvarchar(100) = NULL,
@address nvarchar(500) = NULL
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET XACT_ABORT ON  

BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO [Resource_Control].[Location] ([name], [address])
SELECT N'@name', N'@address'

COMMIT
```

name and address column are both nvarchar
do i need N before my parameters ?
and if so did i put them in right place ?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need them.

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87545/3/0)**

```
INSERT INTO [Resource_Control].[Location] ([name], [address])
SELECT N'@name', N'@address'
```

will insert values '@name' and '@address' into columns.

You need to use:

```
INSERT INTO [Resource_Control].[Location] ([name], [address])
SELECT @name, @address;
```

You use `N''` for string literals not variables like:

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(100) = N'text';
```